# What is the correct pinyin for 哪儿?

Tags: pinyin

I've seen both `Nǎ'er` and `Nǎr`.

The first form looks more like a literal transcription of each character, while the second one  might be the way it's pronounced (assuming there is a difference)

I do understand pinyin is just a learning / transliteration tool; I'm more interested in the explanation of the cases where this conversion is applied and why.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

儿 in this case indicates the application of 儿化 (er2hua4) or 'r-coloring' to the previous syllable.

To input 哪儿 using a typical Pinyin IME, you would have to type `naer` or `na'er`, because `nar` would be segmented `na r`, and the IME would then expect further input for a second Pinyin syllable beginning with `r`.

Outside of keyboard input, however, the correct Pinyin for 哪儿 is `nǎr`, because 儿 is not being used to represent a full syllable. Where it represents a full syllable, it would be represented as `ér` in Pinyin.

Comment: Yes, the correct romanization is "-r"; it's incorrect to romanize it as "-er". If you want a more official source, Pinyin.info has a scanned exerpt from "Chinese Romanization: Pronunciation and Orthography" by Yin Binyong confirming this.

Comment: Great explanation. With it, I was also able to find this article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erhua

Comment: Here's a [link to the page](http://pinyin.info/readings/zyg/rules.html) @Ironfrost mentioned.